# How to get a list of user dialogs from the database of all messages using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a table in the database with messages, namely:

`| Id | FromId | ToId | Text | Date | Read |`

Here's what the class looks like:

```cs
public class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IdentityUser From { get; set; }
    public IdentityUser To { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool Read { get; set; }
}
```

I need to form a request to get a list of all the user's dialogs using the Entity Framework Core. I've sketched out a sample SQL query:

```sql
SELECT FromId, MAX(Date) as updated_at, sum(Read) as new_messages 
FROM (SELECT FromId, Date, Read 
FROM Messages 
WHERE ToId = 'f3578a36-208c-4504-8f3c-afa564455537' 
UNION SELECT ToId, Date, 0 
FROM Messages 
WHERE FromId = 'f3578a36-208c-4504-8f3c-afa564455537' 
ORDER BY Date DESC) as talks 
GROUP BY FromId 
ORDER BY Date DESC;
```

where `f3578a36-208c-4504-8f3c-afa564455537" is the Id of the user whose dialog list I want to get.

However, I can't execute it using the Entity Framework (or don't know how). Is there any way to do this using only EF? I use SQLite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using EF I would write it down like this, I'd query separately for messages from and to user and group them appropriately:

```
var chatsFromUser = dbContext.Messages
    .Where(m => m.From.Id == "f3578a36-208c-4504-8f3c-afa564455537")
    .GroupBy(m => m.To.Id);
var chatsToUser = dbContext.Messages
    .Where(m => m.To.Id == "f3578a36-208c-4504-8f3c-afa564455537")
    .GroupBy(m => m.From.Id);
```

But, I would also suggest that you should define `ID`s properties for users in `Message` entity class:

```
public class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IdentityUser From { get; set; }
    // choose appropiate type, GUID maybe?
    public string FromId { get; set; }
    public IdentityUser To { get; set; }
    // choose appropiate type, GUID maybe?
    public string ToId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool Read { get; set; }
}
```

Then query would be slightly simplified as you could access IDs directly from message object:

```
var chatsFromUser = dbContext.Messages
    .Where(m => m.FromId == "f3578a36-208c-4504-8f3c-afa564455537")
    .GroupBy(m => m.ToId);
var chatsToUser = dbContext.Messages
    .Where(m => m.ToId == "f3578a36-208c-4504-8f3c-afa564455537")
    .GroupBy(m => m.FromId);
```